# whats biggest joint of lamb I can use in a 3.5L slowcooker

Tags: slow-cooking, lamb

Im looking to buy a slowwcooker.  Whats the biggst joint of lamb I can put in a 3.5L slow cooker.

Comment: This is unanswerable. What shape is the lamb joint? What shape is the slow cooker?

Comment: (curious) what do you mean by a "joint of lamb" ?

Comment: "joint of lamb" could be anything from boned, rolled & tied to half a leg, hence my opening comment. Unless the description 'joint' is a UK-only term & you don't recognise it?? [Google images will give you a million examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22joint+of+lamb%22&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ALeKk01xjyvJlq1smZX9DM-iP3b_j_vyeQ:1607963555248&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQwpaE883tAhWSQhUIHcOhCwUQ_AUoAXoECBoQAw&biw=1168&bih=1329)

Comment: Your right, i ment shoudler wiht bone,  I tried delete question but wouldn't let me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a slow cooker for as big a piece of meat as will fit in it and still allow the lid to close. There is no strict need for extra room in the crock.

That said, you will probably want some extra room for spices, stock, et cetera. But so long as you can physically fit all your ingredients, it'll all work.